# How to distinguish MVC and Web Forms Request in a Http Module

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.Net web application which has both MVC and Web Forms. There is an Http Module (`IHttpModule`) to handle certain common tasks for both MVC and web forms. But now there few ***common*** things which should not happen for certain MVC actions.

Can anyone tell me.

How can I detect a given request is an MVC request or a web forms request inside the BeginRequest of the `IHttpModule`?

Comment: What routing do you have on your webforms? You could test for the .aspx extension of webforms if you are using them?

Comment: I am not sure to answer this question "What routing do you have on your webforms?" This is an old web forms application and we have added mvc routing after some time to have certain mvc controllers. Yes as you suggested we can use the extension I thought that is not the best solution. we have url rewriting . hmm but anyways it should get the original page anyways.. should work I'll try this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can tell by the Viewstate in the page source. Check in Web Forms because the page has a __VIEWSTATE field

and for MVC
Check the HTTP response headers. ASP.NET MVC 1.0 generated pages will have:

X-Aspnetmvc-Version:1.0

Comment: Assuming that any response header is present is a bit risky. They might not be present.  For security/obfuscation reasons I remove anything that isn't absolutely necessary. I certainly don't want to tell the client that it's talking with an MVC site. I would split traffic on url instead.